# Comparing two columns in a worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in a worksheet of Title `Name List 1` and `Name List 2`.

I want to compare these two columns and highlight in red which name is not present in `Name List 1` but present in `Name list 2` and vice versa. If names are common in both columns then leave it as white.

The range of the columns of both list is not the same.

```
Sub indicators()
    lastrowlist1 = Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowlist2 = Range("K1000000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lastrowlist1
        Range("C" & i).Value = findval
        For j = 5 To lastrowlist2
            If Range("K" & j).Value <> Range("C" & i).Value Then
                Range("K" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Else
                Range("K" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Use conditional formatting, or at least show your effort and tell us what part of your code you'r stuck on

Comment: The thing about conditional formatting is that it slows down the excel workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VBA, columns A,B

```
Sub duplicates()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim var As Variant

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      var = Application.Match(Cells(i, 1).Value, Columns(2), 0)
      If Not IsError(var) Then
         Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 255
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like it's Coloring for blank cells as well.

Comment: I fixed it. I just wrote the same for comparing column B as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have the following:

```
    A        B
1   Peter    Peter
2   James    Sarah
3   Claire   John
4   Sandra
5   John
```

I can now apply conditional formatting for each column.

1. Highlight `A1:A5`
2. Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...
3. Formula: `=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$3,0))`
4. Apply format
5. Highlight `B1:B3`
6. Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...
7. Formula: `=ISERROR(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$5,0))`
8. Apply format

That should highlight the names you need i.e. appear in one list but not the other.